# Windows 7 BSOD on startup

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod

I got a BSOD today after getting home from 11 hours of work...

1. It seems to work in SAFE MODE (sometimes, not always)
2. The BSOD says:

   > SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
   >   STOP: 0x0000003b
   >   WimFsf.sys - Address FFFFF88001A6B76B base at FFFFF88001A600000, DateStamp 4a5bc362.
3. Sometimes it shows the welcome screen, shows the destkop for a few seconds and then BSODs

Already did:

- unplugged all the USB devices
- reset the CMOS

I haven't installed any new software recently.

What should I do?

**EDIT:**
I've managed to get into safe mode and it seems to works fine.
When I go into normal mode it shows the desktop then it freezes...

Is it more likely to be a software or hardware problem?

**EDIT2:**

I've managed to get into normal mode by disabling all the non-microsoft services & startup programs.
One more thing: When I shut down my PC, on the "Logging off" screen appear some artifacts. I don't think it's because of my graphics card cause I've opened Black OPS and it worked fine. It's so strange... 
It still BSODS on startup (but there a ~=10% that it will not), and when it doesn't BSOD's it works fine...

**EDIT3:**
It sometimes gives a MEMORY_MANAGEMENT bsod.
When I turn on the PC in normal mode the desktop background images doesn't fully load and some artifacts appear on it. But if I try to play a game that uses the GPU it works fine.
Also, error code 0xc00000000e9 appeared.

**EDIT4:**
I think I'll get all the BSOD error codes :)).

Last one: **page_fault_in_nonpaged_area**

Answer (score 3):

System restore is probably what you want to try, however, if it doesn't work, you may want to save your data and consider doing a clean install of Windows 7

Comment: ... I hate reinstalling the Windows, so time consuming...  I've managed to get into Windows (normal mode) and use the PC for about 3minutes then I've got the BSOD again... :(

Answer (score 1):

When you say:

> shows the desktop

are you meaning that you have logged on and the explorer shell loads, and then it crashes?

If you haven't logged on yet, then you could try booting with the [Last Known Good Configuration](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Using-Last-Known-Good-Configuration). If it crashed after logging on, then this isn't going to help you I'm affraid.

An alternative would be to use [System Restore](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-system-restore/)

Comment: Yes, I can log on. Sometimes even nod32 finishes loading and then it crashes, sometimes it doesn't even boot, sometimes it gives DISK ERROR message on a black screen...

Comment: It sounds like your best option is to reboot into safe mode and try system restore.

Comment: Did, nothing has changed...

Answer (score 1):

You might have a hard drive error. Try booting off a livecd and/or using a disk scan utility like [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm).

Answer (score 0):

What is [Winfsf.sys](http://www.softwaretipsandtricks.com/sys/1504-Wimfsfsys.html)

.

> The SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION bug check has a value of 0x0000003B. This indicates that an exception happened while executing a routine that transitions from non-privileged code to privileged code.
>
> The following actions might prevent an error like this from happening again:
>
> Download and install updates and device drivers for your computer from Windows Update.
>
> Scan your computer for computer viruses.
>
> Check your hard disk for errors.
>
> [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff558949(v=VS.85).aspx)

.

Run a chkdsk on the hard drive, 2 ways to do it

Inside Windows

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/guide-to-using-check-disk-in-windows-vista/

.

Booting from a W7 DVD

http://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=6565

.

Scan for viruses

> Follow the order given below to disinfect your PC
>
> 1.) On a PC that is Not infected, Make a boot AV disc then boot from the disc on the Infected PC and scan the hard drive, remove any infections it finds, I prefer the Kaspersky disc myself. The New 2010 Kaspersky disc can update the AV dat files if you are connected to the internet at the time of scan and is suggested to update before the scan.
>
> http://www.techmixer.com/free-bootable-antivirus-rescue-cds-download-list/
>
> 2.) Then:
>   Install free MBAM, run the program and go to the Update tab and update it, then go to the Scanner Tab and do a quick scan, select and remove anything it finds.
>
> http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html
>
> 3.) When MBAM is done install SAS free version, run a quick scan, remove what it automatically selects.
>   http://www.superantispyware.com/download.html
>
> These last 2 are not AV softwares like Norton, they are on demand scanners that only scan for nasties when you run the program and will not interfere with your installed AV, these can be run once a day or week to ensure you are not infected. Be sure you update them before each daily-weekly scan.

Comment: Some news: The prime95 test says "FATAL ERROR: rounding was 0.5 expected less than 0.4 " on a blend test. I tryed to increase the core voltage, still same error.